# Cordova build failed with aapt2 Unknown chunk type '200'

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-android

I have build issues with `cordova@11` + `cordova-android@10.1.2`, with an empty app, I get

```
aapt2.exe W 07-07 09:09:11  9232  8132 LoadedArsc.cpp:682] Unknown chunk type '200'.
```

I've updated all SDK and build tools in Android Studio.
Here's my config

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="test.app" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloCordova</name>
    <description>Sample Apache Cordova App</description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="https://cordova.apache.org">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />        
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />        
    </platform>
    <preference name="scheme" value="app" />
    <preference name="hostname" value="test.app" />
    <preference name="deployment-target" value="12.0" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="23" />
    <preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="32" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="32" />
    <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" /> 
    <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="true" />
</widget>
```

Then the build appears successful but then if I add any plugin, I get device not ready (not fired for 5 sec). How do I debug this?

Comment: How did you fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change your build target to 30. I don't think build tools can build SDK32 yet.

Answer (score 4):

upgrade gradle plugin.
I upgrade compileSdkVersion to 34 , And show those error, So I upgrade gradle plugin to 7.3.1, the error resolved

Comment: This is precisely what I was missing while fixing the AAPT2 issue.
Thank you it saved my time.
Cheers